# Load Image in only one canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, xmlhttprequest

**UPDATED**

I have an `HTML` code below:

```
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

I have a function below:

```
var Context;

function onSign(canvas){
    var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas).getContext('2d');     
    SigWebSetDisplayTarget(ctx);
    tmr = setInterval(SigWebRefresh, 50);
}   

function SigWebSetDisplayTarget( obj ){ 
    Context = obj;      
}
```

I called the function `OnSign` twice with different `canvas id` parameters.

```
OnSign('canvas1');
OnSign('canvas2');
```

Below is the SigWebRefresh function that is repeatedly called for a reason.

```
function SigWebRefresh(){
    xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requests.push(xhr2);  

    xhr2.open("GET", baseUri + "SigImage/0", true );
    xhr2.responseType = "blob"

    xhr2.onload = function (){
        var img = new Image();      
        img.src = 'image.jpg';  

        img.onload = function (){                   
            Ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            revokeBlobURL( img.src );
            img = null;
        }
    }   
    xhr2.send(null);
}
```

After that, I noticed that the two canvas was being updated and the image is loaded to the `2 canvas`. Why is it? I have to load the image, only to the last canvas I supplied with the function `OnSign`. Where am I missing?

Comment: Not replicable for me at - https://jsfiddle.net/50L8op1j/1/

Comment: @DexTer --> I updated my post above for the clarification of my real problem.

Answer (score 0):

`var Context;` is declared in global scope

```
OnSign('canvas1');
OnSign('canvas2');
```

Doing so you are assigning value of canvas number two.

**Update**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmynvtLd/2/

This is what you desired to update both contexts? if yes this is how you pass the parameter to setInterval function: `setInterval(function() {SigWebRefresh(ctx)}, 300);`

running example:

```
    var images = ['http://img09.deviantart.net/6d02/i/2015/284/0/b/beginning_autumn_by_weissglut-d9cssxw.jpg', 'http://orig06.deviantart.net/063c/f/2013/105/3/6/free_crystal_icons_by_aha_soft_icons-d61tfi1.png', 'http://img15.deviantart.net/b126/i/2015/118/c/1/this_small_tree_by_weissglut-d8re8q7.jpg',             'http://img00.deviantart.net/84f8/i/2015/284/d/f/nuclear_light_by_noro8-d9cs4u6.jpg'];

function OnSign(canvas){
    var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas).getContext('2d');     

    tmr = setInterval(function() {SigWebRefresh(ctx)}, 300);
}   


OnSign('canvas1');
OnSign('canvas2');

var index = 0;
function MyIndex()
{
   // console.log(index);
    index = images.length == index ? 0 : index+1;
    return images[index];

}

function SigWebRefresh(Context){
    var img = new Image();      
    img.src = MyIndex();              
    img.onload = function (){           
        Context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);           
        img = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: but in my case the image is loaded in the two canvas. Why is it? It should be on canvas2 only.

Comment: I updated my post above for the clarification of my real problem.

Comment: @Aliyah but only last canvas is updating http://jsfiddle.net/bmynvtLd/, do you want both to update? I don't understand your problem..